# What is the best approach to comeup with the output below in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

What is the best approach to come up with the output below in SQL Server?

Query from Table 1 below and have an out like Table 2.

| Date | Time | In/Out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2022 | 0800H | IN |
| 8/1/2022 | 0802H | IN |
| 8/1/2022 | 1700H | OUT |
| 8/2/2022 | 0810H | IN |
| 8/2/2022 | 1700H | OUT |
| 8/3/2022 | 0800H | IN |
| 8/3/2022 | 1700H | OUT |
| 8/3/2022 | 1710H | OUT |

Last IN First OUT Rule

| Date | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/1/2022 | 0802H | 1700H |
| 8/2/2022 | 0810H | 1700H |
| 8/3/2022 | 0800H | 1700H |

> As described in this image
> [image: original requirement]

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 have reached end of life several years ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call this Gap & Island, the grouping in this case is naturally defined, we do not need to do any extended analysis to identify the groups. It does become _G&I_ when we want to see before and after lunch breaks, or to try and identify when lunch breaks occur, but it is over-complicating the issue for the simple requirement that is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this set a simple `CASE` statement can be used to separate the *INs* from the *OUTs*:

```
SELECT [Date]
      , MAX(CASE [IN/OUT] WHEN 'IN' THEN [Time] END) AS [IN]
      , MIN(CASE [IN/OUT] WHEN 'OUT' THEN [Time] END) AS [OUT]
FROM Times
GROUP BY [Date]
ORDER BY [Date]
```

When the conditions get more complicated I prefer to use CTE syntax:

```
WITH TimeData as (
  SELECT [Date],[Time],[IN/OUT]
    , CASE [IN/OUT] WHEN 'IN' THEN [Time] END AS IN_TIME 
    , CASE [IN/OUT] WHEN 'OUT' THEN [Time] END AS OUT_TIME 
  FROM Times
)
 SELECT [Date]
      , MAX(IN_TIME) AS [IN]
      , MIN(OUT_TIME) AS [OUT]
 FROM TimeData
 GROUP BY [Date]
 ORDER BY [Date];
```

Both produce the same result set: (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/52750/1 )

| Date | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 0802H | 1700H |
| 2022-08-02 | 0810H | 1700H |
| 2022-08-03 | 0800H | 1700H |